# Vue.js, cocoon and Rails nested forms

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vue-component

I have a working implementation of a custom checkbox as follows:

```
<div class="vue-checkbox">
  <checkbox :is-checked="false" 
            label-text="Checkbox Label Text" 
            value="user"></checkbox>
  <%= f.hidden_field :checkbox-value %>
</div>
```

This leverages Rails built in form field generation, and uses the following code to sync the field with the component:

```
toggle: function () {
  this.checked = !this.checked;
  $(this.$parent.$el).find('input[type="hidden"]')
    .val(this.checked ? this.value : '');
}
```

Setting it up in this way lets me use Rails' built in form helpers, and [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to generate nested form fields dynamically. I'm just wondering if there is a better way of syncing the field than going through the components $parent.$el? Something more Vue-ish?